# Deleting lines in a file with Python generates error

Tags: python

I use this code:

```
with open("engl_bible.txt", 'r') as f:
    new_f = f.readlines()
    for line in new_f:
        if "#" not in line:
            f.write(line)
f.truncate()
print(f)
```

to delete the lines that begin with # but it generates the following error

```
f.write(line)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

what did I get wrong here? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You opened file in read mode. So `write` does not work. Use `'r+'` for both reading and writing.

Comment: You need to open the file in writing mode : `with open("engl_bible.txt", 'wb') as f:`

Comment: Also note that doing this, might place the file pointer at the end of the file (since you've read the entire file), thus you'll simply be writing more to the file rather than writing over data. Especially if you do `readlines()` first and then iterate over the list of rows.

Comment: @TonyPellerin No he can't, that would generate `io.UnsupportedOperation: read` if he tries to read the contents.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the shortest answer I can give you, that appears to be working:

```
with open("engl_bible.txt", 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    for line in lines:
        if "#" in line: continue

        f.write(line)
```

You need to open the file in both read and write mode, after you've read the file you then need to make sure you stand at the beginning and truncate the file to make sure you don't get any trailing text.

Then you go ahead and iterate over all the lines you've read in, and write those you want to write.

There are better ways of doing this, but this will solve your problem and hopefully you'll learn something about file handles.

The problem you were facing, was as @Austin pointed out that your file is in read mode. Meaning you can't write to it. You can't open it in write mode only, because that would make it impossible to read from it. Where as `r+` opens for both reading and writing.

Do remember tho, after each character read in a file the position "marker" will move one character forward. So writing something while reading is a bit tricky and dangerous *(but this could potentially speed things up)*. So the easiest way is to read the whole file, and jump back to the beginning and do the work you want to do.

Other ways would be to read each line, check if you want it, if not, jump back one line, replace that line. But then you'll have to worry about trailing data or data getting partially replaced etc. Anyway, keep this in mind.

---

As @Swift pointed out, an old habit of mine is to do the *"skip if X"* logic at the top of the loop, that way I know that all the code in the block is supposed to execute and it's only related to the task rather than having a bunch of if cases later along the line.

Never the less, the code could be shortened to this as well:

```
with open("engl_bible.txt", 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    for line in lines:
        if not "#" in line:
            f.write(line)
```

And it would do the same. Thought I'd throw it in there since the question was raised.

Comment: Isn't the `continue` redundant here? Without explicitly telling it to stop, it will continue to iterate by default, no?

Comment: It's a perhaps odd way of doing logic, it just checks if the line is a comment and tells the loop to skip whatever code you have below. It's a habbit of mine to put the "if not" checks at the very start of the loop. You could do `if '#' not in line: f.write(line)` as well. But usually you want to do more with the line than just re-write it to the file, which makes a `continue` check/one-liner pretty neat and tidy - that way you know that everything that follows in the loop is supposed to execute. But you're correct, it is redundant for this very narrow task.

Comment: I wasn't criticising but more trying to understand if there was an effect on the code, but it sounds like it's just a sanity check :) Thanks for explaining.

Comment: No offense taken, gave me a good little ponder as well why I was doing it that way. So I appreciate it! But there's no effect on the code except a little sanity check ^^ Have a good one! :)

Comment: I have a theory, did you start out writing Python in 2.x? Personally I've never written much at all in 2.x and bulk of my experience is 3.x and perhaps that's the difference?

Comment: Great answer by the way. Beats mine haha.

Comment: Yea started out.. well in Python 1.x :P But I mainly do 3.X coding, feels better to be in the future rather than stuck in old versions. If possible, I do try my best to be cross-version compatible, but if I can't I always go with v3.X comparability. Code is usually way faster in 3.X. Heh, thank you. I thought you had some good points in your answer.

Comment: @James - Don't forget to mark the answer as the solution, whichever you feel is the proper one :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("engl_bible.txt", 'rt') as f:
    new_f = f.readlines()
    for line in new_f:
        if "#" not in line:
            f.write(line) #The problem is here, you open in read mode but attempt to write to the file.
f.truncate()

print(f)
```

The problem in your code is due to the first line. As explained in the comment section, you are asking Python to open the file in read-only mode. This means you can get the data from it, but you cannot write to it.

My suggestion would be to open it in write mode, either write-text or write-binary `wt or wb`

If you really must write, I would also further suggest you create a new file rather than over-writing the old file, then archive or delete the old file as applicable.

To do this follow this code instead:

```
important_lines = []
with open("engl_bible.txt", 'rt') as f:
    new_f = f.readlines()
    for line in new_f:
        if "#" not in line:
            important_lines.append(line)
f.truncate()

print(f)
with open("engl_bible_cleaned.txt", 'wt+') as f:
    for item in important_lines:
        f.write(item)
```

Comment: `f.readlines()` causes `IOError: File not open for reading` / `io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable` depending on which version of Python you're using. Also `wt` is the default when doing just `w`. Further more, you should test your code before you give out the answer - just to avoid confusion :)

Comment: This would still open the file in write mode

Comment: Sorry, I copied his code before changing that. I have amended the answer

Comment: Why did you edit you comment lol? I really hate people like you on here.... all you're doing is criticising where it's not necessary. And giving negative feedback for something that is 100% correct and acceptable. I even go out of my way to explain what is wrong with his code and offer and improved code. But thanks dude... your input is completely not appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Open the file get the lines and then reopen the file in write mode, which will truncate the file and write the data you want to it.

```
with open("t.txt", 'r+t') as f:
   new_f = f.readlines()
with open("t.txt", 'wt') as f:
   for line in new_f:
     if "#" not in line:
     f.write(line)
```

Comment: Same as my answer pretty much

Comment: So it's the same as my answer and you just want to be cheeky. Good one internet stranger lol.

Comment: didn't really mean to be - at the time i was writing up my answer, it wasn't correct. It is now though, besides i got negative feedback event though my answer was always correct :)

Comment: People like to jump to conclusions on here. Kind of annoying but I'll get over it.